# How to edit capacity or queue of wireless node in NS2?

Tags: tcl, ns2

I need to monitor packets dropping in ns2, but I can't figure out how to edit wireless node capacity.

In wired simulations, we can set the capacity as follows:

```
$ns_ queue-limit $n(0) $n(1) 5 #num of packets.
```

but it doesn't work in wireless situation since there is no link between nodes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer in `queue length` when defining physical card properties:

```
set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue ;
set val(ifqlen)         50                      ;
```

where `ifqlen` is the queue length.